# Java/C++ - Getting 3d line from Camera yaw (heading) and pitch (no roll)

Tags: java, c++, math, 3d

I'm aware of Quaternion methods of doing this. But ultimately these methods require us to transform all objects in question into the rotation 'space' of the Camera.

However, looking at the math, I'm certain there must be a simple way to get the XY, YZ and XZ equations for a line based on only the YAW (heading) and PITCH of a camera.

For instance, given the normals of the view frustrum such as (sqrt(2), sqrt(2), 0) you can easily construct the line (x+y=0) for the XY plane. But once the Z (in this case, Z is being used for depth, not GL's Y coordinate scrambling) changes, the calculations become more complex.

Additionally, given the order of applying rotations: yaw, pitch, roll; roll does not affect the normals of the view frustrum at all.

So my question is very simple. How do I go from a 3-coordinate view normal (that is normalized, i.e the vector length is 1) or a yaw (in radians), pitch (in radians) pair to a set of three line equations that map the direction of the 'eye' through space?

NOTE:

Quaternions I have had success with in this, but the math is too complex for every entity in a simulation to do for visual checks, along with having to check against all visible objects, even with various checks to reduce the number of viewable objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 nx = (float)(-Math.cos(yawpos)*Math.cos(pitchpos));
 ny = (float)(Math.sin(yawpos)*Math.cos(pitchpos));
 nz = (float)(-Math.sin(pitchpos)));
```

That gets the normals of the camera. This assumes yaw and pitch are in radians.

If you have the position of the camera (px,py,pz) you can get the parametric equation thusly:

```
x = px + nx*t
y = py + ny*t
z = pz + nz*t
```

You can also construct the 2d projections of this line:

```
0 = ny(x-px) + nx(y-py)
0 = nz(y-px) + ny(z-pz)
0 = nx(z-pz) + nz(x-px)
```

I think this is correct. If someone notes an incorrect plus/minus let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Use any of the [popular methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles#Matrix_orientation) out there for constructing a matrix from yaw and pitch to represent the camera rotation. The matrix elements now contain all kinds of useful information. For example (when using the usual representation) the first three elements of the third column will point along the view vector (either into or out of the camera, depending on the convention you're using). The first three elements of the second column will point 'up' relative to the camera. And so on.

However it's hard to answer your question with confidence as lots of things you say don't make sense to me. For example I've no idea what "a set of three line equations that map the direction of the 'eye' through space" means. The eye direction is simply given by a vector as I described above.

Comment: space is three dimensions. To properly map the direction of the eye through space, you require three two dimensional line equations: x,y; x,z; y,z. Converting the yaw and pitch to a line should not require matrix multiplications.

Comment: In computer graphics a line is frequently represented by either (1) a point on the line and a direction or (2) two points on the line. I've worked in graphics for 20 years and have never used three 2d equations. Describing an orientation with pitch and yaw is describing it as the composition of a pair of rotations. Matrices are convenient for composing rotations. But you don't need to actually use any matrices. Just use the formulae for the individual elements as in the link I gave. I've successfully found the camera direction vector 100s of times like this.

Comment: Fair enough, but providing a link where you might be able to answer the question for yourself isn't the same as answering it.

Comment: I didn't simply provide a link. I described how you can read the information you want from a matrix, and a bunch of other information, and provided you with a link to the matrix. Did I move you forward with your problem? If not, tell me which bit you don't understand and I'll provide even more consultancy services without expectation of recompense.

Comment: You didn't **have** to answer either. You chose to try to answer. So I think you did your best. Thanks for trying.